# Populate values to checkbox while editing in zend framework

Tags: zend-framework, checkbox

I am trying to populate the values into check box. I want check box to be checked when there is value stored in database.

This is my code in form:

```
$form ['test_1'] = new Zend_Form_Element_Checkbox('test_1');
$form['test_1']->setLabel('test1')->setCheckedValue('1');

$form ['test_2'] = new Zend_Form_Element_Checkbox('test_2');
$form['test_2']->setLabel('test2')->setCheckedValue('2');
```

If there is value `1` in database i want first check box to be checked and if its `2` then 2nd checkbox needs to be checked.

What do i need to do in the controller.

Could anyone please help me on this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way would be to fetch the values from the database as an array that maps to the form input elements, e.g. return a row like

```
array('test_1' => 'value of checkbox', 'test_2' => 'value of checkbox');
```

You could then simply call `$form->populate($values)` and let do `Zend_Form` do the setting, e.g. in your controller do

```
public function showFormAction()
{
    $form = $this->getHelper('forms')->get('MyForm');
    $data = $this->getHelper('dbGateway')->get('SomeTable');
    $form->populate($data->getFormData());
    $this->view->form = $form;
}
```

Note: the helpers above do not exist. They are just to illustrate how you could approach this. Keep in mind that you want [thin controllers and fat models](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3499336/in-mvc-where-do-you-draw-the-line-between-a-controller-and-model/3501048#3501048), so you should not create the form inside the controller, nor put any queries in there.